# how do i print text to a document in c# without manual formatting?

Tags: c#, printing

As in I do no want to use the print class and place the text manually, say drawstring or drawline or draw rectangle . Is there a formatting tool that I can use to output the content on to a printer in a formatted way ? 
For eg :

```
void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics graphic = e.Graphics;
        Font font = new Font("Courier New", 12);
        float fontHeight = font.GetHeight();


        int startX = 10;
        int startY = 10;
        int offset = 40;

        graphic.DrawString("OPTIQUE INDIA", new Font("Times New Roman", 18), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 250, startY);
        string name = fname.Text + " " + lname.Text;
        string Age = age.Text;
        string date = dateTimePicker1.Text;
        graphic.DrawString("Name : " + name, new Font("Courier New", 12), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
        graphic.DrawString("Age : " + Age, new Font("Courier New", 12), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 450, startY + offset);
        graphic.DrawString("Date : " + date, new Font("Courier New", 12), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 450, startY + offset * 2);

        startY += offset * 2 + 40;
        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

        Pen blackPen = new Pen(brush, 4);
        graphic.DrawRectangle(blackPen, startX, startY, 750, 200);

   }
```

In the above code I'm trying to place the content manually . As in I just know the approximate position as to  where the text might appear but not the exact place, I have to check the output every time and adjust the code in order get the text appear at the right place.

So is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: please share what did you do.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the streamreader you need to add a boolean[TRUE], This will make the streamwriter format the file when it is initialized. It will also create the file if it does not exist.

Example:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath, true);
```

You can also use this simple function and add it where you want the file to be formatted

Example:

```
private void FileCheck(string fp)
{        
    if (File.Exists(fp))
    {
        File.Delete(fp);
        File.Create(fp);
    }
}
```

This is not so efficient though (and the code sucks, i know :P).